# "Impossible to connect to JIRA" error on SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube5.1

I'm trying to link a Sonar issue to Jira using "Link to Jira" option, but getting "Impossible to connect to Jira - https://{Jira URL}.atlassian.net/.

I was able to create a JIRA with same configuration 8months ago, but not now. Not sure if JIRA has changed anything to force importing SSL certs to Sonar JRE now.

Could you please let me know how to get the Jira SSL cert and import it to the Sonar keystore?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The SSL part of the connection isn't related to SonarQube, it's standard Java security. To your question, assuming the error is indeed a trust issue (you didn't provide debug logs):

- Retrieve the server certificate:

  ```
  echo -n | openssl s_client -connect JIRA_HOST:port | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > server.pem`
  ```
- Add it to Java truststore:

  ```
  keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias jira_server -file server.pem -keystore /<java_install>/jre/lib/security/cacerts
  ```

  (default truststore password is `changeit`)